# "fatal error: Index out of range" in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to make an app that allows you to loads images from an array, and I keep getting a `fatal error: Index out of range`. It will very randomly crash when I press an image in the collection view to send it to a detail view controller. Here is the code for my array:

```
func loadArray(){

    imageArray = []

    let userImages = PFQuery(className: "Image")
    userImages.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userImages])

    query.includeKey("user")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(result: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let result = result {
            for object in result{

                let imageFromParse = object["imageFile"] as! PFFile
                imageFromParse.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if let data = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data, scale: 0.05)!
                        print("image: \(image)")
                        self.imageArray.append(image)
                        print("doublecheck: " + String(self.imageArray))
                    }
                    if self.refreshControl.refreshing
                    {
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    }

                    self.cellView?.reloadData()
                    let targetIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.imageArray.count-1, inSection: 0)
                    self.cellView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([targetIndexPath])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    print("imageArray print \(self.imageArray)")
}
```

It seems to be breaking on this line: `let passedImage = imageArray[realIndex.row]`
when I pass the image to the detail view.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toDetailView" {
        let destController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        let selectedCellIndex = cellView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()
        let realIndex = selectedCellIndex![0]

        let passedImage = imageArray[realIndex.row]
        print(passedImage)
        print(selectedCellIndex)
        print(realIndex)
        destController.passedImageInDetailView = passedImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the last lines, that ones that reloads the table, could cause the error. Try instead reloading the table only with `self.cellView?.reloadData()` and comment out the two below. And make sure that you have override [`- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) and return something like `self.imageArray.count`.

Comment: I commented out those two lines, and no luck. And I don't quite follow the last part, as Im using a collection view.

Comment: What you are doing isn't very "safe". You are modifying an array in a background thread and arrays aren't thread safe. In your load function you clear the array but don't reload the collectionview, so there may be items displayed that no longer exist.  You are probably better off storing your array of PFObjects which gets returned from the query and then fetching the images as required in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.  You can use a PFImageView in your cell to make this easier

Comment: Have you tried moving `'self.cellView?.reloadData();  let targetIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: self.imageArray.count-1, inSection: 0);  self.cellView?.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([targetIndexPath])` part inside the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change line

```
let passedImage = imageArray[realIndex.row]
```

to line

```
let passedImage = imageArray.dropFirst(realIndex.row).first
```

2. Your problem may be that `func prepareForSegue` starts when `loadArray()` is not finished, so you have an empty array after calling `imageArray = []`